# decode the day and compare with a column

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have columns:

1.:`delivery_date` column.. It returns the day of the week, like this:

```
1  --monday
2  --tuesday
3  --wednesday
4  --thursday
5  --friday
```

2.: `date` column.. It returns the date of the pick up - it's a normal date column - example: `25.03.2019 (format DD.MM.YYYY)`

**But,** our system automatically compare & sets the `date` to the nearest  `delivery_date`.

Example:

the partner has `delivery_date` **every week** on thursday and on tuesday.. [so 4 and 2]. He wants to pick up the goods on friday. At this time our system changes the `date` to thursday. But i want the next `date`, which is tuesday - **and i want to decode it to date (format DD.MM.YYYY)**

So output be like:

```
--if pick up date: 22.03.2019 (friday)
--partner has delivery_date: 4,2(thursday, tuesday)

I want to get: 26.03.2019 --as output
```

I can compare the columns.. that's not problem.. But how can i decode the "actual pick up" date ?

How can i do that ?

Comment: Don't you mean [so 4 and 5] ?

Comment: Can't you be consistent? There are Thursday, Friday, Tuesday and Wednesday in your message. Do you even know *What happened to Monday?*

Comment: @OldProgrammer I mean tuesday (Friday was my mistake). The point: I want to get the next `deliver_date`, but not in format 1,2,3,4,5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solving this problem, it may be an advantage to construct a "calendar" table - make this big enough (!), which can subsequently be used to densify your data (see comments in the code below).  For testing, let's use the following tables (Oracle 12c, 18c):

**Table CAL_**

```
create table cal_
as
select sysdate + level date_
, to_char( sysdate + level, 'Day' ) dname_
, to_char( sysdate + level, 'D' )   dnumber_
from dual
connect by level <= 31 ;  -- number should be big enough to cover the lifetime of your system

SQL> select * from cal_ ;
DATE_      DNAME_     DNUMBER_  
17-MAR-19  Sunday     7         
18-MAR-19  Monday     1         
19-MAR-19  Tuesday    2         
20-MAR-19  Wednesday  3         
21-MAR-19  Thursday   4  
...
12-APR-19  Friday     5         
13-APR-19  Saturday   6         
14-APR-19  Sunday     7         
15-APR-19  Monday     1         
16-APR-19  Tuesday    2
```

**Table DELIVERYDAYS**

```
create table deliverydays ( partner, deliveryday, dayofweek )
as
select
  mod( level, 3 ) + 1 
, mod( level, 5 ) + 1
, to_char( sysdate + ( mod( level, 5 ) + 2 ), 'Day' )
from dual
connect by level <= 10 ;

-- partner 4 delivers on Tue and Thu (same days as in the question)
insert into deliverydays ( partner, deliveryday, dayofweek )
values ( 4, 2, 'Tuesday' ) ;
insert into deliverydays ( partner, deliveryday, dayofweek )
values ( 4, 4, 'Thursday' ) ;

SQL> select * from deliverydays order by partner, deliveryday ;
PARTNER  DELIVERYDAY  DAYOFWEEK  
1        2            Tuesday    
1        4            Thursday   
1        5            Friday     
2        1            Monday     
2        2            Tuesday    
2        3            Wednesday  
2        5            Friday     
3        1            Monday     
3        3            Wednesday  
3        4            Thursday   
4        2            Tuesday    
4        4            Thursday   

12 rows selected.
```

You can [DENSIFY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1014934) your data like this.  Notice that the gaps in between the delivery days become visible. (Column names with trailing underscores: from the CAL_ table).

```
select 
  partner, deliveryday , dayofweek 
, date_, dname_, dnumber_
from deliverydays D partition by ( partner )
  right join cal_ C on D.deliveryday = C.dnumber_
where partner = 4
order by date_ ;

PARTNER  DELIVERYDAY  DAYOFWEEK  DATE_      DNAME_     DNUMBER_  
4        NULL         NULL       17-MAR-19  Sunday     7         
4        NULL         NULL       18-MAR-19  Monday     1         
4        2            Tuesday    19-MAR-19  Tuesday    2         
4        NULL         NULL       20-MAR-19  Wednesday  3         
4        4            Thursday   21-MAR-19  Thursday   4         
4        NULL         NULL       22-MAR-19  Friday     5         
4        NULL         NULL       23-MAR-19  Saturday   6         
4        NULL         NULL       24-MAR-19  Sunday     7         
4        NULL         NULL       25-MAR-19  Monday     1         
4        2            Tuesday    26-MAR-19  Tuesday    2         
4        NULL         NULL       27-MAR-19  Wednesday  3         
4        4            Thursday   28-MAR-19  Thursday   4  
...
-- 31 rows selected
```

As a next step, you could use the LEAD() function, for finding the "next" delivery dates,
then calculate the amount of days between "picking up" and delivery, and format the dates as required.  (See the "commented" version of the query [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ea2c0649cc3e93ae2bbe5b6268c23d1).)

```
select pid, dday, next_dday, date_, dname_, dnumber_
, case 
    when dnumber_ > next_dday then ( 7 - dnumber_ + next_dday ) -- next week
    else next_dday - dnumber_
  end ddiff_
, case
    when dnumber_ > next_dday then
      to_char( date_ + ( 7 - dnumber_ + next_dday ), 'DD.MM.YYYY' )
    else 
      to_char( date_ + ( next_dday - dnumber_ ), 'DD.MM.YYYY' )
  end delivered_on 
from (
  select  
    partner as pid, deliveryday as dday
  , lead( deliveryday ) ignore nulls over ( order by date_ ) as next_dday
  , dayofweek 
  , date_, dname_, dnumber_
  from deliverydays D partition by ( partner )
    right join cal_ C on D.deliveryday = C.dnumber_
  where partner = 4 -- partner id
)
where to_char( date_, 'DD.MM.YYYY' ) = '22.03.2019' -- "pick up" date
order by date_  ;
```

**Result**

```
PID  DDAY  NEXT_DDAY  DATE_      DNAME_     DNUMBER_  DDIFF_  DELIVERED_ON  
4    NULL  2          22-MAR-19  Friday     5         4       26.03.2019
```

Without using the outer WHERE clause, we get ..

```
PID  DDAY  NEXT_DDAY  DATE_      DNAME_     DNUMBER_  DDIFF_  DELIVERED_ON  
4    NULL  2          17-MAR-19  Sunday     7         2       19.03.2019    
4    NULL  2          18-MAR-19  Monday     1         1       19.03.2019    
4    2     4          19-MAR-19  Tuesday    2         2       21.03.2019    
4    NULL  4          20-MAR-19  Wednesday  3         1       21.03.2019    
4    4     2          21-MAR-19  Thursday   4         5       26.03.2019    
4    NULL  2          22-MAR-19  Friday     5         4       26.03.2019    
4    NULL  2          23-MAR-19  Saturday   6         3       26.03.2019    
4    NULL  2          24-MAR-19  Sunday     7         2       26.03.2019    
4    NULL  2          25-MAR-19  Monday     1         1       26.03.2019    
4    2     4          26-MAR-19  Tuesday    2         2       28.03.2019    
4    NULL  4          27-MAR-19  Wednesday  3         1       28.03.2019    
4    4     2          28-MAR-19  Thursday   4         5       02.04.2019 
...
-- 31 rows selected
```